# Как правильно подключать чужие библиотеки к android-проекту в eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android, java, package

Взял файл [DashboardLayout.java](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java), положил его свой `src/com.my.project/`, изменил в нем строчку `package` на `package` `com.my.project`. Но подозреваю, что можно подключить и не изменяя чужие ресурсы. А как это делается правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, package указывает на нахождение файла. Толком он ни на что не влияет. Если хотите, не меняйте, используйте те же пути, что были в исходном файле, но, я повторюсь, package придумали лишь для структуризации проекта, дабы вам было удобно использовать другие классы.

А еще package используеться андроид маркетом, там он должен быть уникальным. Ну, можете в [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package) почитать.

Answer (score 0):

Сторонние классы и пакеты в Adndroid подключаются точно так же, как в обычном java приложении, когда все пакуется в один jar файл.